# Extract part of server name in Apache RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's suppose that I have a file in the filesystem like this:

```
/documentroot/domains/foo/files/resource.html
```

I want to write a rule so that `http://foo.example.com/resource.html` serves the file `/domains/foo/files/resource.html`. But if the request URL is `http://bar.example.com/resource.html`, it should look inside `/domains/bar/files/resource.html`. What I've accomplished so far is this, which works correctly:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/foo/%{REQUEST_URI}" -f
RewriteRule ^ domains/foo/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

How can I generalize this, for any domain name? I was thinking of applying a regular expression to the `%{SERVER_NAME}` variable, but I can't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^domains/ domains/%1/files%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```