# Is there any option to redirect wildcard domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am redirecting

`xyz.com` to `user.xyz.com`.

But I can't redirect `user.xyz.com/anythingelse`.

Here is my .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.xyz.com
RewriteRule (.*)  shop.php?username=%1
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:php] when your question is about [tag:mod-rewrite]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your RewriteCond should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.com
```

Because you want to apply the rule only to the domain `xyz.com`, and not any subdomain.
The rule becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://user.xyz.com/$1
```

This redirects every page to the same page of the new website.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$  https://user.xyz.com/anypage.php
```

This allows you to access from the homepage (with or without the last "/") the page `https://user.xyz.com/anypage.php`

Comment: not working at all. actually, I have already redirected xyz.com ==> user.xyz.com but I want to open user.xyz.com/anypage.php from user.xyz.com page. but every time I got user.xyz.com page only.

Comment: If I undestood correctly you're trying to access `user.xyz.com/anypage.php` from `user.xyz.com`?

Comment: It's working but now  in previous code  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.xyz.com
RewriteRule (.*)  shop.php?username=%1  can't working

Comment: i want user.xyz.com and access to user.php?user_id

Comment: i want to access username

Comment: Check this question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010328/extract-part-of-server-name-in-apache-rewriterule

Comment: It's Woking Rightly now